# How to append voice to a powerpoint slide already with voice?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, voice

Is there a way to append voice to a powerpoint slide that already has some voice in it?

In Powerpoint (Office 2013), under `Slide Show` -> `Record Slide Show`, there are only two options for recording:

```
Start Recording from Beginning ...
Start Recording from Current Slide ...
```

*In each case, the existing voice in a slide is overwritten*. Sometimes I recorded a long voice in a slide and then found later that I needed to add new voice to the end of the existing voice.

Is there way to do that with Powerpoint (or a similar software)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to independently record the additional sound (for example, in a different presentation file), then extract it, add it to your presentation and apply animations to make it play immediately after the previous sound.

Possibly simpler:  extract the existing sound, open it in a sound editor (Audacity is free/good/capable) then put the edited sound back in place of the original.

By far the simplest way to do this in Windows is to download/install 7Zip (also free). It can open PPTX files directly. Once you open the file as a ZIP, go to the media folder where you'll find your sounds; that's how you can extract them/replace them.